# How do I get specific parts of JSON files for use with HTML?

Tags: java, html, json

I would like to import JSON data from a file, the code I have at the moment is:

```
<script>                            
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {             
    var output = "<tr>";
    for ( var i in data.users) {
    output += "<td>"
    + "-- "
    + data.users[i].time
    + " --<br>-- "
    + data.users[i].senderID
    + " --<br>"
    + data.users[i].message
    + "<br></br></td>";
    }
    output += "</tr>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
</script>
```

But I can no longer access it as it doesnt get generated with a nice neat name like "users" as you can see below it is "¬í t’" but you cant reference to that as part of it isnt valid characters

```
    ¬í t’{  
    "messageId": 53,  
    "userTo": {    
    "userId": 4,    
    "userName": "Bob123",    
    "userLastCheckedDate": "Mar 7, 2013 11:14:53 AM"
    },

    "userFrom": {
    "userId": 1,
    "userName": "Joe123",    
    "userLastCheckedDate": "Mar 7, 2013 10:41:44 AM"
    },

    "messageContent": "a lovely message here",
    "messageSentDate": "Mar 7, 2013 11:36:14 AM",
    "messageReadDate": "Mar 7, 2013 12:49:52 PM"
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Also, this is the java that generates the JSON

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(userMessages.get(0));
    out.write(json);

    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\web\\data.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);   
    oos.writeObject(json);
    oos.close();
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `data.json` file or code of the script that generates it? Either you choose wrong keys or you have wrong encoding set.

Comment: Are you sure, its correct JSON format. Why is it `¬í t’`?